# how can I get congestion information from google maps APIs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For my project I need to extract congestion information through a route obtained from Google's map API. I went through Google's Direction API, it just provides information regarding the estimated time of travel through that route. Please Help. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe currently there is no any endpoint to get this information from Google. You might be interested in the following feature request that I can see in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65322481

Please star this feature request and add a comment that explains your use case.

**UPDATE**

It looks like the feature request mentioned above was rejected by Google (I assume this is also a reason for downvote).

There is another feature request for real-time traffic data for a particular route on maps

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36537583

The latter is still valid and marked as Assigned and Neat Idea.

Please star the feature request everybody who is interested in it.